# How to keep + and - in ng-pattern using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help. I have one text field which should not take the alpha numerical value but take `numbers,+,-,.` using Angular.js . I am explaining my code below.

```
<div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.lati.$touched && billdata.lati.$invalid }">
<input type="text" name="lati" id="latitude" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Latitude coordinate" ng-model="latitude"   ng-keypress="clearField('businessno');" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/">
</div>
```

But here problem is while this field has value like `-122.32379000000003`,its showing the error message.here i need this field only can accept `numbers,+,- and .` white space are also not allowed with alphanumerical value. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use `/^[.+-]?[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/`

Comment: Please offer some explanation to improve the quality of your answer. See here for help on [Writing a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You need to allow the +- bevore the first numbers, since the origin regExp only allows strings starting with a number.

Answer (score 0):

To meet the requirement , you can use the below pattern

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/"
```

Example:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.lati.$touched && billdata.lati.$invalid }">
<input type="text" name="lati" id="latitude" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Latitude coordinate" ng-model="latitude"   ng-keypress="clearField('businessno');" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/">
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Change you ng-pattern regex to `ng-pattern="/^([\-\+0-9]{0,1})(\.?[0-9])*$/"`

where `^([\-\+0-9]{0,1})` which allows +,- or numbers as a first character

```
    <form name="myForm">
        <div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.lati.$touched && billdata.lati.$invalid }">
          <input type="text" ng-pattern="/^([\-\+0-9]{0,1})(\.?[0-9])*$/" name="lati" id="latitude" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Latitude coordinate" ng-model="latitude" ng-keypress="clearField('businessno');" >
      </div>
      <label ng-show="myForm.lati.$error.pattern">Error</label>
  </form>
```